# Android get just Contact Name from Contact id

Tags: android

salam
i know the answer is simple , but i cant find it
i try this :

```
   Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
     contact_id);

   Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

   cursor.moveToFirst();

   while(cursor.moveToNext()){
     String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
   }
```

what's wrong ?
.
.

.

Comment: just remove `cursor.moveToFirst();`

Comment: thank's but it was not able to get any results back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in URI Path

```
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            contact_id);

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
              query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToNext();

        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.
             getColumnIndexOrThrow
                 (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
```